# Sum of criteria from multiple col and rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can someone please help me create an Excel formula? Here is what the table looks like.

[image]

What I need is to sum up all cols that are after Jan and have model number 1.

Comment: Can you show us the expected output? Are you expecting (a) individual monthly totals at the bottom of each month column, OR, (b) are you expecting a single value which sums every "01" model across all months together, OR (c) something else. If (a), then Jan conditional total would be 201 (100+101), Feb's = 206, Mar's = 202 and Apr's = 199. If (b), then the answer would be conditional totals across all months i.e. 201+206+202+199 = 808.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest two different methods,

1. Get Column total except Jan for Model 1.
2. Get total of all Columns except Jan for Model 1.

[image]

- Formula in Cell `D209` to get Column total:

`=SUMIFS(D$206:D$208,$B$206:$B$208,1)`

*Fill formula Right.*

- Formula in Cell `F211` to get total of all 
  Columns:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($D$206:$F$208)*($B$206:$B$208=1))`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*